# How do I get ChangsetIds from iterating through WorkItemLinks

Tags: c#, workitem

I have an application that currently takes a list of workitemIds. When you enter a workitemId. The application brings back the changsets for that workitemId and all workitems changesets that are related to the workitem that was entered in.

Here is my current working code.

[image]

I want the application to filter out "successor/predecessor " workitems that are related to the workitem entered in. In essence I want to see the workitem that was entered in changesets AND the workitems changesets that are related to workitem entered in, but I don't want to see changesets that are predecessor/successor workitems.

The only way i've found of doing this is by using the WorkItemLink collection that has a linktypeend.linktype.referencename

[image]

I can't find a property that exposes the changeset id.. So I need a few answers

1.How do I expose the linkedartifacturi so I can get the changesetID for the workitemlink.
2. How do I filter out items with "system.linktypes.dependency" (successor/predecessor)?

Comment: Please post code as text in your question, not as images.

Comment: It wouldn't format properly. Do you have answer, or any type of suggestion?

Comment: The code in the image looks well formatted. If you paste it into your answer, you should then select the code and click the icon in the edit pane that looks like a pair of curly brackets. Then the code will be highlighted properly.